# Android Studio make video width relative to the video height

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to make the background a video but to get the right aspect I need the height to match_parent and then the width to scale relative to the height. Is there any way of doing this?

The only way I have done it so far is to set the width manually, but this means it will look squashed or stretched on some devices as the height changes.

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vv_menu_card_animation"
    android:layout_width="1280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ConstrainLayout, you can also define one dimension of a widget as a ratio of the other one by layout_constraintDimensionRatio. You can read more here: [ConstrainLayout: Ratio](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#ratio).

If you want width = height, you can add this line to your VideoView:

> app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
> android:layout_width="0dp"

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vv_menu_card_animation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
 />
```